# PicklingError: Could not serialize object (happens only for large datasets)

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, pyspark-pandas

Context: I am using pyspark.pandas in a databricks jupyter notebook.

What I have tested:
I do not get any error if:

- I run my code on 300 rows of data.
- I simply replicate the dataset 2 times (600 rows by pd.concat).

I get an error if:

- I simply replicate the dataset 10 times (3000 rows by pd.concat)

This makes me think the error is not code specific rather databricks might have an intricacy or some limitation..

Can someone explain what might be happening. It's a very big repository so I haven't included the full code.

Exact error:
**PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object**

Full trace:

```
/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/pipeline.py in apply_criteria(self)
    408 
    409             time1 = time.perf_counter()
--> 410             self.scores_df[ [f'{field}__{criteria}' for field in fields_for_criteria[criteria] ] ]= self.rem.apply(lambda x: self.apply_criteria_across_all_fields(x,criteria),axis=1,result_type="expand")
    411             time2 = time.perf_counter()
    412             print(time2 - time1)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/usage_logging/__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    192             start = time.perf_counter()
    193             try:
--> 194                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    195                 logger.log_success(
    196                     class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, args, **kwds)
   2555                 self_applied, apply_func, return_schema, retain_index=True
   2556             )
-> 2557             sdf = self_applied._internal.to_internal_spark_frame.mapInPandas(
   2558                 lambda iterator: map(output_func, iterator), schema=return_schema
   2559             )

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/map_ops.py in mapInPandas(self, func, schema)
     79         udf = pandas_udf(
     80             func, returnType=schema, functionType=PythonEvalType.SQL_MAP_PANDAS_ITER_UDF)
---> 81         udf_column = udf(*[self[col] for col in self.columns])
     82         jdf = self._jdf.mapInPandas(udf_column._jc.expr())
     83         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in wrapper(*args)
    197         @functools.wraps(self.func, assigned=assignments)
    198         def wrapper(*args):
--> 199             return self(*args)
    200 
    201         wrapper.__name__ = self._name

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in __call__(self, *cols)
    175 
    176     def __call__(self, *cols):
--> 177         judf = self._judf
    178         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    179         return Column(judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _judf(self)
    159         # and should have a minimal performance impact.
    160         if self._judf_placeholder is None:
--> 161             self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
    162         return self._judf_placeholder
    163 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _create_judf(self)
    168         sc = spark.sparkContext
    169 
--> 170         wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
    171         jdt = spark._jsparkSession.parseDataType(self.returnType.json())
    172         judf = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction(

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _wrap_function(sc, func, returnType)
     32 def _wrap_function(sc, func, returnType):
     33     command = (func, returnType)
---> 34     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
     35     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes, sc.pythonExec,
     36                                   sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   2848     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
   2849     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
-> 2850     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
   2851     if len(pickled_command) > sc._jvm.PythonUtils.getBroadcastThreshold(sc._jsc):  # Default 1M
   2852         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py in dumps(self, obj)
    481                 msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, emsg)
    482             print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 483             raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
    484 
    485 

PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Answer (score 0):

pickling would arise if something is being serialized for Spark.
If it's pandas on Spark, then I think the issue may be that you're pickling a pandas DF.
it's a pandas on Spark DF. You can't use that inside a Spark task, same as it's always been with Spark. Make that a pandas DF if it's just a small lookup
Make it pandas instead with .toPandas() and it should work

Comment: While I will give a try to what you have recommended , I do think that the error has a correlation with the size of the pyspark.pandas dataframe - As the code runs successfully for 300 and 600 samples but fails for 3000 samples. I have tried running on each sample ~10 times