# How to use Parallel processing using Concurrent Jobs in Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, pyspark-pandas

**A. Background:**

1. I have to text  manipulation using python (like concatenation , convert to spacy doc , get verbs from the spacy doc etc) for 1 million records
2. Each record takes 1 sec, meaning it will take 10 days for 1 million records !
3. There's no ML model I am using. It's just basic text manipulation using python

**B. High level problem :**

Speed up the above run using concurrent jobs that databricks has.

**C. I have been recommended the below steps but unsure of how to proceed.**

1. I have been recommended to create a table in Databricks for my input data (1 million rows x 5 columns).
2. Add 2 additional columns - Result Column and Status Column (with entries NaN/InProgress/Completed) to the table
3. Split the table into 10 jobs such that the records with Status=NaN are sent for processing (python script), and the Status is updated to InProgress/Completed depending upon the script's completion for that record..
4. Have been asked to use spark dataframe in python script instead of pandas dataframe.

**D. What I have tried already:**

1. I have simply changed my Python code from [Python Pandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html) to [Pyspark.Pandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html) (which is a Pandas API for Spark and is supposed to work similar to Spark Dataframe.. )
2. But with above ^ , I have not been able to achieve much improvements - My python code executed 30% faster for 300  records , but I think that's just because of a better Databricks  processor (Azure cloud)
3. For larger records , my databricks noteboook gives a Pickling Error which I have described in detail in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469453/picklingerror-could-not-serialize-object-happens-only-for-large-datasets)